# Getting gpsd address for ntpd

Tags: linux, ntpd, gps

I'm working through some tutorials for setting ntpd clock from gpsd. The guides that I'm working from list adding something like this:

```
server 127.127.46.0 
fudge 127.127.46.0 time1 0.0 time2 0.0 refid GPS
```

to `/etc/ntp.conf` however every tutorial seems to use a different ip e.g. `127.127.28.0` or `127.127.40.0` etc.

What do these addresses correspond to, and how can I find out the correct one to use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that the loopback ip-address range `127.127.0.0/16` is used by NTPD to represent drivers for specific clocks. The **third octet** is the number of the specific driver as found on the list of drivers [here](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/refclock.html#list) and should probably correspond to either your actual clock or to how you want to interact with gpsd.

The **fourth octet** is the "unit number", which was originally meant to be used in case there were multiple devices on a system supported by the same driver, although in some cases it gets used differently.

As far as I can tell no driver actually connects over TCP/IP to that loopback address, it appears a NTPD quirk to name/represent drivers as loopback ip-addresses.

The pseudo IP-address **`127.127.28.0`** therefore indicates a specific driver in NTPD, specifically [driver 28, the shared memory driver](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/drivers/driver28.html) SHM and is one way gpsd and ntpd can interact.

**`127.127.46.0`** denotes a different driver, [driver 46, the GPSD NG client driver](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/drivers/driver46.html) a specific client driver to interact with gpsd.

Comment: Correct. The fourth octet is the "unit number", which was originally meant to be used in case there were multiple devices on a system supported by the same driver, although in some cases it gets used differently. In the case of driver 46, `127.127.46.`x instructs gpsd to open `/dev/gps`x, which serves the original purpose, but the high bit is overloaded for a special purpose.

Answer (score 5):

**All IPv4 addresses in the 127/8 netblock are reserved for host loopback.** However, only 127.0.0.1 is commonly used.

[RFC 5735, section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#section-3).

> 

127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host
loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an
address anywhere within this block loops back inside the host.  This
is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback.  As
described in [[RFC1122], Section 3.2.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3), addresses within the entire
127.0.0.0/8 block do not legitimately appear on any network anywhere.

Having different addresses used for different purposes when all addresses end up in the same place is useful:

- for traffic separation e.g. in firewall rules
- for any services that do not support virtual hosting

Generally speaking, as long as your system routing tables are set up to allow for 127/8 as loopback, you can use any 127/8 address you want, as long as you are consistent on the server and client sides.